# Passing value from onResponse to onPostExecute keep turning to null

Tags: java, android

I'm connecting to API with the async task. I need to pass two values from the API to the app, in onResponse I have logged the values and got them right. But in onPostExecute one of them keep turning into null

I have already tried to check different values from API and logs to see if the value that I'm looking for is there or if the connection is valid, everything went alright until it hits the onPostExecute where I'm getting only one value

```
public class ChooseLocationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            //default timeout for not annotated requests
            .readTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
    Request request;


    private TextView location;
    private TextView value;
    String state;
    Number probability;
    String probablityString;

    public ChooseLocationTask(TextView location, int selected, TextView value){
        this.location = location;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...values){
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        request = new Request.Builder().url(urls[0]).build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("CallMsg", String.valueOf(call));
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d("Response", String.valueOf(response));
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONObject weather = jsonObject.getJSONObject("weather");
                    JSONObject location = weather.getJSONObject("location");
                    state = location.getString("state");

                    JSONObject percentage = jsonObject.getJSONObject("probability");
                    JSONObject calculated = percentage.getJSONObject("highest");
                    probability = calculated.getInt("value");
                    probablityString = probability.toString();
                    Log.d("percentage", probability.toString());
                    Log.d("String",probablityString);
                    Log.d("location",state);

                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void voids){
        if(isCancelled()){
            voids= null;
        } else {
            location.setText(state);
            value.setText("your chance to see Northern lights today is" + probablityString);
            Log.d("value", "onPostExecute: " + probablityString);
        }
        Log.d("post", "onPostExecute: " + probability);
    }

}
```

Basically, all I need is advice on how to get this value, I feel like maybe I made mistake when converting it into a string, but in logs, in onResponse it shows quite alright, so I don't know. Thank you for all the advice

Comment: Can you add your entire AsyncTask code please? My hunch is that you're running your request in a separate thread to your AsyncTask, so calling anything in `onPostExecute` would occur before the request has finished, but I'd need to see more code to verify that.

Comment: Yeah, it's as I suspected - you don't need an `AsyncTask` as `enqueue()` is already asynchronous. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit has two techniques for performing requests, one synchronous (`execute()`) and another asynchronous (`enqueue()`). You are using the asynchronous technique, and as a result, when you go to execute your `AsyncTask`, your `doInBackground()` method immediately calls `enqueue()`, completes, and calls `onPostExecute()` before your request has completed.

You have two options. First, you can keep your current AsyncTask, but replace `enqueue()` for `execute()`. This will look a little like:

```
public class ChooseLocationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            //default timeout for not annotated requests
            .readTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
    private final Request request;


    private final TextView location;
    private final TextView value;
    String state;
    Number probability;
    String probablityString;

    public ChooseLocationTask(TextView location, int selected, TextView value){
        this.location = location;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        request = new Request.Builder().url(urls[0]).build();

        try {
            final Response<?> response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                final JSONObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(response.body().string());
                //etc...
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
           //...
        }

        //I'd recommend you return values as well, rather than assigning them to
        //instance variables
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void voids){
        if(isCancelled()){
            voids= null;
        } else {
            location.setText(state);
            value.setText("your chance to see Northern lights today is" + probablityString);
            Log.d("value", "onPostExecute: " + probablityString);
        }
        Log.d("post", "onPostExecute: " + probability);
    }
```

Or, you can get rid of your `AsyncTask` entirely, and just call `enqueue()`

Comment: If I do private final request, I cannot assign a value to it in DoInBackground - or that is at least the thing that android studio is telling me. Also do I understand correctly that from this I don't need on Response?

Comment: Fair enough. `request` can become a local variable. You don't need the callback if you use `execute()` - the method call returns the `Response`, so you can use it directly.

Comment: Just a question, what should there be instead of the question mark in final Response? Because I keep having errors while building json object, so I'm wondering if that could help me with it.

Comment: It depends on the error, but the "?" is a wildcard value you can replace with an explicit type ([see Call#execute](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#execute--)). If you post the error you're seeing I can try and modify my answer to help you.

Comment: You are so kind, thank you! I managed to get rid of the errors in the catch, apparently, it wanted two exceptions. Now I'm just fighting with the place where I can add the explicit type, I tried to add there the request is written in the documentation you send me, because I'm using okhttp but it doesnt like it nor does it like all the other types I wrote there, I might have misunderstand it

Comment: Update your question to include your revised code and I can take a look at it in my IDE. It's difficult to visualise the problem based on your description.

Comment: Damn, sorry, I accidentally edited your answer instead of my question